# How can i run a website locally developed using .NET

Tags: .net, iis, web

I've developed a website in .NET using Visual Studio 2008. I gave this website to my friend using USB pendrive. Now he wants to run that website locally on his PC in which Visual Studio is not installed. Please suggest me how can i run locally that website in my friend pc. Where should i save that website on his PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install .NET runtime, and host it in his local IIS. The requirement is that IIS has the website set up pointing to the appropriate folder. (For example, save the website in 'c:/inetpub/website name' and point IIS's website directory to that same folder. You will also need to make sure that IIS_USR has read access to this folder.)

For example, the hosted server I use does not have Visual Studio installed, we simply ship the code up and run it through IIS and .NET installed without visual studio.

Comment: hypothetically speaking if a friend doesn't want to install IIS for whatever reason, is it possible to run that website by installing VS Express?  Or would that be too much overkill compared to just IIS?

Comment: @DXM - I know there's the visual studio development server, but that's only a temporary thing, you could try to keep that running (would only be able to access the site via a specific port: http://localhost:5138/). But MSFT is going the route of IIS Express rather than VS Development Server for the future if I'm not mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that, really. You'll need at least IIS to be installed on your friend's computer. It can be obtained by visiting http://www.microsoft.com/ and looking for it in the Downloads section. From there, set it up and move your project into the root directory.

Comment: Yes  i installed IIS in his PC. Now what should i do to change in Virtual Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Your friends' computers need to be installed with IIS.  Once that's installed, your friends need to move your web 'materials'(pages and executables) to the virtual directory that can be specified in the IIS services tab

Comment: Yes  i installed IIS in his PC. Now what should i do to change in Virtual Directory?

Comment: If your web sites/applications are simple web sites/applications, you can just move whatever in your own virtual directory that hosts your web sites/applications to his, with the same structure too.

Comment: Yeah it is very simple site. But sir i am unable to find out what should i do in virtual direcory,please provide me steps to make virtual directory for my site. and what should i use in address bar of browser to run? and in which directory of folder i should store that site contents.